# Show the following derivability fact: $\exists x : (P(x) \land x = c),\quad \forall x(P(x) \implies Q(x)) \vdash Q(c)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I've come across the following question:

> Show the following two derivability fact:
>
> $\exists x : (P(x) \land x = c),\quad \forall x(P(x) \implies Q(x)) \vdash Q(c)$

Now I'm not really sure where to start here. The solution provided uses a tableau, but I strongly dislike those, so am looking for other ways to show the same thing.

Comment: If you're interested in a practical formal system for mathematics (not just toy examples like this one), you can look at my profile under "Natural deduction".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7) :

> 1) $∃x(P(x) ∧ x=c)$ --- premise
>
> 2) $∀x(P(x) \to Q(x))$ --- premise
>
> > 3) $P(a) ∧ a=c$ --- from 1) for $\exists$-elim (here we start the subproof)
> >
> > 4) $P(a)$ --- from 3) by $\land$-elim
> >
> > 5) $a=c$ --- from 3) by 4\land$-elim
> >
> > 6) $P(a) \to Q(a)$ --- from 2) by $\forall$-elim
> >
> > 7) $Q(a)$ from 4) and 6) by $\to$-elim [aka : *Modus Ponens*]
> >
> > 8) $Q(c)$ --- from 5) and 7) by $=$-elim [aka : *substitution of equality for formulas* : $x = y → (φ[z/x] → φ[z/y]$)](here ends the sub-proof)
>
> 9) $Q(c)$ --- from 1) and 3)-6) by $\exists$-elim.

Comment: I follow everything aside from step $6$. If we have $(P(a)\land a) = c,\quad Q(a)$; how does $Q(c)$ follow from this? Are distributing the $=$ and saying that $(P(a) = c) \land (x=c)$?

Comment: @MitchellFaas - No; we use $a=c \to (Q(a) \to Q(c))$ and *Modus Ponens*-

Comment: Oh, okay; so yeah we're distributing the $=$, saying that $(P(a)\land a)=c \implies  (P(a)=c)\land(a=c)$. I didn't think you could make this step. EDIT: Nevermind, I see now. You're not doing that, you're interpreting as: $\exists x : (P(x) \land (x=c))$.

Comment: Yes, @MitchellFaas That bracketing should be $P(a)~\wedge~(a=c)$